# Unable to init microstack

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, keystone

I'm trying to install openstack on ubuntu 20.04 server but init fails.
Can someone please explain why this error and any suggestions?

````
2022-04-29 12:08:28,706 - microstack_init - INFO - Setting up as a control node.
2022-04-29 12:08:40,467 - microstack_init - INFO - Generating TLS Certificate and Key
2022-04-29 12:08:44,707 - microstack_init - INFO - Configuring networking ...
2022-04-29 12:09:01,841 - microstack_init - INFO - Opening horizon dashboard up to *
2022-04-29 12:09:04,997 - microstack_init - INFO - Waiting for RabbitMQ to start ...
Waiting for 192.168.219.131:5672
2022-04-29 12:09:06,279 - microstack_init - INFO - RabbitMQ started!
2022-04-29 12:09:06,280 - microstack_init - INFO - Configuring RabbitMQ ...
2022-04-29 12:09:09,530 - microstack_init - INFO - RabbitMQ Configured!
2022-04-29 12:09:09,606 - microstack_init - INFO - Waiting for MySQL server to start ...
Waiting for 192.168.219.131:3306
2022-04-29 12:09:10,857 - microstack_init - INFO - Mysql server started! Creating databases ...
2022-04-29 12:09:13,539 - microstack_init - INFO - Configuring Keystone Fernet Keys ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/microstack/245/bin/microstack", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('microstack==0.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'microstack')()
  File "/snap/microstack/245/lib/python3.8/site-packages/microstack/main.py", line 44, in main
    cmd()
  File "/snap/microstack/245/lib/python3.8/site-packages/init/main.py", line 60, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/snap/microstack/245/lib/python3.8/site-packages/init/main.py", line 228, in init
    question.ask()
  File "/snap/microstack/245/lib/python3.8/site-packages/init/questions/question.py", line 210, in ask
    self.yes(awr)
  File "/snap/microstack/245/lib/python3.8/site-packages/init/questions/__init__.py", line 482, in yes
    check('snap-openstack', 'launch', 'keystone-manage', 'db_sync')
  File "/snap/microstack/245/lib/python3.8/site-packages/init/shell.py", line 69, in check
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, " ".join(args))
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'snap-openstack launch keystone-manage db_sync' returned non-zero exit status 1.```
````

Comment: make sure that your system is up-to-date and clean. by clean i mean no extra services like mysql or apache installed before. check your open ports to see which services is running. this error shows that it cant sync keystone database. so there has to be a  problem with the db.

Answer (score 1):

mostly the problem is the required port is used by another process(in use).

#check if the port is in use:

```
sudo lsof -i:[port]
```

Comment: I had MySql running on 3306 due to which my MicroStack installation was stalled. It worked after I ran `service mysql stop`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't had lxd installed and solved by running:

```
sudo snap install lxd && sudo lxd init
```

After that, just run the following command again and you're done:

```
sudo microstack init
```